# Плавное появление блоков

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на троеточие очень плавно появлялись другие кнопки? `transition` что-то не срабатывает...

```js
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
for (var i = 3; i < buttons.length - 2; i++) {
     buttons[i].style.display = "none";
}

var dots = document.querySelector('ul li span');
dots.onclick = function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
         buttons[i].style.display = "inline";
     }
     dots.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
    ul > li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #c7c7c7;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Следующая</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li style="cursor: pointer"><span>...</span></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Предыдущая</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: transition не будет работать с display:none; как вариант - использовать opacity:1 (виден)/ 0 (скрыт), вместо display , тогда будет работать transition

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь, теперь есть из чего выбрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `transition` не обрабатывает дискретные значения(прерывистые, состоят из отдельных значений, например `block`, `inline`, `inline-block`...), а только 
аналоговые(например цифры, цвета).

Для примера сделаем `opacity: 0`, а при клике будет изменять его на `opacity: 1`. Добавим `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out`, но у нас снова ничего не работает, почему? Ответ не так очевиден, все из-за движка обрабатывающего JavaScript, а точнее его `event-loop`, он обрабатывает и меняет значения css свойств, но не дает время для его отрисовки браузером. Решить можно так - завернуть наше изменение свойства в setTimeout - `setTimeout(() => buttons[i].style.opacity = 1, 0)`. SetTimeout с нулевым значением, смысл? А смысл в том, что между этими функциями будет происходить передачи контроля браузеру и он будет отрисовывать нашу анимацию.

PS `dots.style.display = 'none'`, нужно присваивать его родителю.

PPS Более подробно с event-loop можно ознакомиться [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
for (var i = 3; i < buttons.length - 2; i++) {
     buttons[i].style.display = "none";
     buttons[i].style.opacity = 0;
}

var dots = document.querySelector('ul li span');
dots.onclick = function () {
     for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
         buttons[i].style.display = "inline";
         setTimeout(() => buttons[i].style.opacity = 1, 0)
     }
     dots.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
    ul > li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #c7c7c7;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Следующая</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li style="cursor: pointer"><span>...</span></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Предыдущая</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот так получилось полностью **плавное появление** кнопок

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for (var i = 3; i < buttons.length - 2; i++) {
  buttons[i].classList.add('hidden');
}

var dots = document.querySelector('.d');
dots.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  dots.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

ul {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

li.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.d {
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">next</a></li>
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">9</a></li>
  <li class="d"><a href="/" onclick="event.preventDefault()">...</a></li>
  <li><a href="">prev</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// генерация разметки кнопок, для компактности примера 
let btnsHtml = (to => { let str = ''; for (let i = 2; i <= to; i++) str += `<li><a href="">${i}</a></li>\n\t`; return str; })(10); 
let list = document.querySelector('ul'); list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML.replace(/<\!--[\s\S]+-->/g, btnsHtml); 

// значимая часть примера начинается здесь 
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(n+3)'); 
for (let btn of buttons)
  btn.classList.add('collapse');

let dots = document.querySelector('ul > li:nth-child(3)');
dots.onclick = function () {
  for (let btn of buttons)
    btn.classList.remove('collapse'); 
  this.classList.add('collapse');
};
```

```css
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #c7c7c7;
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; 
}
ul > li:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2) {
  width: 2ch; overflow: hidden; 
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.5, 1); 
}

ul > li.collapse {
  width: 0 !important; 
  padding: 10px 0; margin: 0 -2px; 
}

ul > li a { text-decoration: none; }
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Следующая</a></li>
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li style="cursor: pointer"><span>...</span></li>
  <li><a href="">2</a></li>
  <!-- не обращайте внимания, кнопки создаются средствами JS -->
  <li><a href="">Предыдущая</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: хороший пример ... лучше моего и лучшего ответа ...

Comment: Спасибо, @Максим!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dots = document.querySelector('ul li span');
dots.onclick = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].slideDown( 'slow' );
  }
  dots.slideUp( 'slow' );
}
```